# Is there a way to unpack a promise once without .then each time?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise, async-await

I'm running an ajax POST to a server to receive JSON data as a promise and I'm looking for a way to unpack the promise and get the [[PromiseValue]] itself (the actual data) without having to use a nested .then() each time. Conceptually, can I unpack the data once (perhaps when I return the new Promise) so that I can just use async await and then start manipulating the data once it's (hopefully) been resolved? Here's my minimum reproducible example:

```
var data = getData();
useData(data);

async function getData() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve({one: 1, two: 2, three: 3});
    return;
  });
};

//This is what I would like to have
async function useData(data) {
  await data;
  console.log(data);  //which I'd like to return the value within [[PromiseValue]]
};

//This is my working version
async function unpackData(data) {
  await data.then((res)=> {
    console.log(res);
  });
};
```

Currently I run unpackData() instead of useData() since useData() logs the promise itself rather than the data, but I'd love a method that lets me work with the PromiseValue after the await data; line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I'm misunderstanding, but why not this?

```
async function useData() {
  const data = await getData();
  console.log(data);
}
```

And if you want to reuse the same promise each time:

```
async function getData() {
  if (!getData.promise) {
    getData.promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      resolve({one: 1, two: 2, three: 3});
    });
  }
  return getData.promise;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Oooh, so close:

```
async function useData(data) {
  const unpackedData = await data;
  console.log(unpackedData);  
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass data then await it. Data must be awaited, then passed, otherwise, you are passing `Promise`, not data. Passing `Promise` is not necessary and not a good idea.

Either `.then()` or `await` will do the job. The difference is only syntactic. In general, try not to mix the two.

```
// either
getData().then(useData);

// or (IIFE-wrapped unless already inside an asyncFunction)
(async function() {
    useData(await getData());
})();
```

Neither `getData()` nor `useData()` needs to be asyncFunction unless they use `await`.

```
function getData() {
    return Promise.resolve({'one': 1, 'two': 2, 'three': 3});
};

function useData(data) {
    console.log(data);
};
```